# An isomorphic map from $\mathbb R^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{*}$

Tags: group-theory

Say the map $\phi$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb R^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{*}$, where $\mathbb R^{*}$ is the group of all real numbers not including $0$ under the multiplication operation.  The map $\phi$ is a bijection such that $\phi (ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b)$.  How would I prove that if $r > 0$ then $\phi (r) > 0$ and if $r < 0$ then $\phi (r) < 0$?

I can think qualitatively why this is true.  For instance, the identity element of $\mathbb R^{*}$ is $1$ and will remain $1$ for any bijection of $\mathbb R^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{*}$ otherwise the mapping will not be a group, thus, not an isomorphism.

In order for $1$ to exist in the group after the mapping, you cannot multiply the elements of $\mathbb R^{*}$ by a constant.

However, I don't know how to prove this mathematically.  Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Are you working on the same homework as this person? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001215/is-this-an-isomorphism-possible/2001219#2001219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: think about whether $a \in \Bbb{R}$is a square: $a = b^2$?